# Cases involving empty lists does not compile when using Filter to remove Nothing cases

Tags: haskell, filtering, empty-list, hspec

For an assignment I have to write a function that uses `filter` on a list of `Maybe` instances, removing all with a value of `Nothing`. We're supposed to make sure the function works using Hspec.

It's simple to get it working with a case containing elements before and after running using `Data.Maybe (isJust)`:

```
onlyJust :: [Maybe a] -> [Maybe a]
onlyJust = filter isJust
```

But, as soon as I try to apply the function to a test case such as

```
it "produces the list []" $
    onlyJust [Nothing, Nothing] `shouldBe` []
```

or

```
it "produces the list []" $
    onlyJust [] `shouldBe` []
```

the test suite file does not compile, giving an ambiguous type error.

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

I've attempted to add a type annotation as the error message suggests, but I cannot find one that matches the type constraints on the function itself. For the latter test case, I've also tried modifying the function by adding an empty case:

```
onlyJust :: [Maybe a] -> [Maybe a]
onlyJust [] = []
onlyJust l = filter isJust l
```

but the error still persists. Am I glossing over an obvious type annotation to fix this issue, or is there a flaw in how the function is written that means it can't handle outputting an empty list or taking one in as input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `onlyJust [Nothing, Nothing]` shouldBe `[]` it does not know what value to pick for the `a` in `Maybe a`, hence the error. You can add a type hint, like:

```
onlyJust ([Nothing, Nothing] :: [Maybe Int]) `shouldBe` []
```

the same for the empty list:

```
onlyJust ([] :: [Maybe Int]) `shouldBe` []
```

Note that there is already a [**`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) which filters out the `Nothing`s and unwraps the items from the `Just …` data constructor.